# Django 1.11: pass id to url to generate detail view

Tags: django

I've a list of "nanas" (babysitters) that I render correctly. Now I need that when someone clicks on one of them , a detail page (for only the clicked nana opens).

I think my problem is on my template for all the Nanas, in the href:

```
<a href="{% url 'app-administrador:nana' nana.id %}">
```

Or in the Urls.

**All Nanas page:**

This is listing nanas View:

```
class NanasView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        nanas = Nana.objects.all()
        context = {'nanas': nanas}
        return render(request, 'app_administrador/nanas-registradas.html', context)
```

It's URL:

```
url(r'^referencias_de_nanas', views.NanasReferenciasView.as_view(), name='referencias_de_nanas'),
```

All Nanas templates:

```
{% extends 'app_administrador/templates/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}


    <!-- Member Entries -->


    {% for nana in nanas %}


        <!-- Single Member -->
        <div class="member-entry">


            <a href="extra-timeline.html" class="member-img">

                <i class="entypo-forward"></i>
            </a>

            <div class="member-details">

                <a href="{% url 'app-administrador:nana' nana.id %}">

                <h4>
                    <p href="extra-timeline.html">{{ nana.nombre }} {{ nana.apellido_paterno }} {{ nana.apellido_materno }}</p>
                    {% if nana.foto %}
                        <img src="{{ nana.foto.url }}" class="img-rounded" width="160px"/>
                    {% endif %}
                </h4>

                <!-- Details with Icons -->
                <div class="row info-list">

                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <i class="entypo-briefcase"></i>
                        <a href={{ nana.antecedentes_policiales }}>Antecedentes policiales</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <i class="entypo-twitter"></i>
                        <a href="#">@johnnie</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <i class="entypo-facebook"></i>
                        <a href="#">fb.me/johnnie</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="clear"></div>

                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <i class="entypo-location"></i>
                        <a href="#">{{ nana.direccion }}</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <i class="entypo-mail"></i>
                        <a href="#">{{ nana.correo }}</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <i class="entypo-linkedin"></i>
                        <a href="#">johnkennedy</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
              </a>

            </div>

        </div>

    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

**Nana's detail page:**

My try on showing the detail page for clicked nana:

```
class NanasValidarReferenciasView(View):
    def get(self, request, nana_id):
        # nana_id_is = nana_id
        nana = Nana.objects.get(id=nana_id)
        context = {'nana': nana}
        return render(request, 'app_administrador/validar-referencias-nana.html', context)
```

It's URL:

```
url(r'^nana', views.NanasValidarReferenciasView.as_view(), name='nana'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see your href looks like this: `<a href="{% url 'app-administrador:nana' nana.id %}">` which is totally fine. This means that the url link adds the two string together into one address. I don't know exactly how your urls are set up so it could look something like this:

```
root_url/2
```

Where root_url is whatever you have and 2 is the `nana.id`. To pass that to the url-view, it needs to accept any integer variable. Something like this:

**urls.py**

```
 url(r'^nana/(?P<nana_id>\d+)/$', views.nanas_specific, name='nana'),
```

The P stands for Parameter, and it uses Regex logic if you want to look that up.

Then in your views, you can have a function ready to accept the parameter:

**views.py**

```
def nanas_specific(request, nana_id):
```

Where nana_id contains the result from the urls parsing.

Comment: Hmm, I see now that you are using class views, not functions. Did this help anyway?

Comment: Yes, it helped. May you expand on the meaning of P and the regex?Thanks.

Comment: Sure, but I dont think I can be better than the official documentation from Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score 1):

I mostly work with function based views, but I'm assuming the same logic applies to classbased views. The id is not part of the URL and hence is not passed on. Change the url to

```
url(r'^nana/(?P<nana_id>\d+)/$', views.NanasValidarReferenciasView.as_view(), name='nana'),
```